# "Create sql function , select english characters?"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a function that selects English numbers and letters only:

Example:

```
TEKA תנור ביל דין in HLB-840 P-WH לבן
```

I want to run a function and get the following result:

```
TEKA HLB-840 P-WH
```

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using mssql server 2012

Comment: This will be tough to swing in SQL Server, which doesn't support regex replacement (which is what you really need here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL-Server is not the right tool for this.

The following might work for you, but there is no guarantee:

```
declare @yourString NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'TEKA תנור ביל דין in HLB-840 P-WH לבן';
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(@yourString AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'?',''),' ','|~'),'~|',''),'|~',' ');
```

The idea in short:

A cast of `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` will return all characters in your string, which are not known in the given collation, as question marks. The rest is replacements of question marks and multi-blanks.

If your string can include a questionmark, you can replace it first to a non-used character, which you re-replace at the end.

If you string might include either `|` or `~` you should use other characters for the replacements of multi-blanks.

You can influence this approach by specifying a specific collation, if some characters *pass by*...

Answer (score 2):

What you really need here is regex replacement, which SQL Server does not support.  Broadly speaking, you would want to find `[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+\s*` and then replace with empty string.  Here is a demo showing that this works as expected:

### Demo

This would output `TEKA in HLB-840 P-WH` for the input you provided.  You might be able to do this in SQL Server using a regex package or UDF.  Or, you could do this replacement outside of SQL using any number of tools which support regex (e.g. C#).

Answer (score 1):

```
create function dbo.AlphaNumericOnly(@string varchar(max))

returns varchar(max)

begin

   While PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', @string) > 0

        Set @string = Stuff(@string, PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', @string), 1, '')

return @string

end
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no build in function for such purpose, but you can create your own function, should be something like this:

```
--create function (split string, and concatenate required)
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanStringZZZ ( @string VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @B VARCHAR(100) = '';
    WITH t --recursive part to create sequence 1,2,3... but will better to use existing table with index
      AS
        (
            SELECT n = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT n = n+1 --
            FROM   t
            WHERE  n <= LEN(@string)
        )
    SELECT   @B = @B+SUBSTRING(@string, t.n, 1)
    FROM     t
    WHERE    SUBSTRING(@string, t.n, 1) != '?' --this is just an example...
    --WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, t.n, 1)) BETWEEN 32 AND 127 --you can use something like this
    ORDER BY t.n;
    RETURN @B;
END;
```

and then you can use this function in your select statement:

```
SELECT dbo.CleanStringZZZ('TEKA תנור ביל דין in HLB-840 P-WH לבן');
```

[image]